# Correct formula for converting the ARIMA MA(1) coefficient to the exponential smoothing $\alpha$ parameter?

Tags: time-series, arima, exponential-smoothing

Two crucial sources for time series analysis differ in a critical formula for equivalence between simple exponential smoothing (SES) and ARIMA(0, 1, 1).

From Hyndman's [F:PP](https://otexts.org/fpp2/arima-ets.html):

$\theta_1 = \alpha - 1$

and from R. Nau's [Statistical Forecasting](https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411arim.htm#ses):

$\theta_1 = 1- \alpha$

Can someone help me understand the apparent discrepancy?

Comment: The ETS model formulation is not the same as simple exponential smoothing.  SES relies on a $-$ sign in front of the term involving the error but ETS has a $+$ sign in front, hence the relationship between the two (different) $\theta_1$s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common parameterizations of ARIMA models. My book follows the R convention, while Nau follows the Box-Jenkins convention. The formulations are both correct and equivalent.

Comment: Would you happen to know which parameterization is used by the python statsmodel statespace library?

Comment: No idea, and the online documentation doesn't seem to clearly specify it.